# Gulp HTTPS certificate

Tags: javascript, gulp

I create application with HTTPS and I have a problem with gulp serve.
In gulpfile.js i have this code:

```
    'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');

gulp.task('serve', serve({
  root: ['public', 'build'],
  port: 443,
  https: {
    key: 'E:\\Public\\certifikat.pfx',
    cert: 'E:\\Public\\certifikat.pfx',
  }
}));

build.initialize(gulp);
```

This is error message:

> ReferenceError: serve is not defined

When I use only this, its work:

```
 'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');

build.initialize(gulp);
```

Thanks for advices

Comment: Maybe you should actually include gulp-serve? `const serve = require('gulp-serve');`

Comment: @kishanoza Please first correct your attitude. What is even the intention of your (pretty rude) comment? What is keeping you from simply editing the question and change whatever you feel is wrong? Also, looking at your questions, answers and comments: He who sits in the glass house shouldn't throw stones.

Comment: @Num Lock - I added code which is success, but dont contains https